# Generate Random String for Model Field in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using DRF and have a couple models where I want to generate unique numbers separate from ID's. For example, one model would have a number like PRJ023400 and another would be TSK2949392.

I created a utility function to generate random numbers and as the field and attempted to use this function as the default.

```
number = models.CharField(max_length = 10,
                          blank=True,
                          editable=False,
                          default='PRJ'+create_new_ref_number())
```

The problem I am facing is that this only generates a new string when running a migration. What would be the best approach to make this work?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

`default` can accept a function. As per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#default):

> The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable
> object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is
> created.

Considering all this you can set it to a function like this:

```
def number_default_function():
    return 'PRJ' + create_new_ref_number()

class YourModel(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(
        max_length = 10,
        blank=True,
        editable=False,
        default=number_default_function
    )
```

Comment: I tried this out but unfortunately it returned the same results.

Comment: @PixelsOfMind your previous approach failed because `default='PRJ'+create_new_ref_number()` was evaluated when the line was evaluated, i.e. default was set to `'PRJ<SOMETHING>'`, If the approach in my answer fails that means that your function `create_new_ref_number` returns the same thing for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually able to figure this out.

For the model field, I changed it to:

```
number = models.CharField(max_length = 10,
                              blank=True,
                              null=True,
                              editable=False)
```

When saving, I added this function to generate a new string each time:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.number = 'PRJ' + create_new_ref_number()
        super(Project, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hopefully this can help someone else out.

Cheers.

Comment: In passing, it's worth being careful if `number` is user-visible, since it leaks information about how many objects you have and the rate of object creation.  That may not be desirable.